# How do you handle stale cache records in mobile app

Tags: android, sqlite, rest, mobile, synchronization

I am in the process of creating an android app (my first) that consumes a REST API.
I use a background job to fetch content and I plan to use a GET request with a from_id parameter in order to get *more* content. Of course anything fetched from the API gets stored in the SQLite db (I am using greendao) and the app only uses data that is already present there, in order to be snappy.

So, the question is: What happens if a given record is updated on the server? If records once read are cached, how come the app will notice that there are changes to sync? Which strategies are feasible solutions?

Thanks.

EDIT:

As Satish P points out in his answer, the client-server communication is handled with ETag (and I must add the possibility of using If-Modified-Since).

But my main concern, is how to mix this with the app UI. Given this example:

1. A list of elements, which have been retrieved from the REST service but client-side are read from the local database to make the app more responsive.
2. User clicks in one of those elements and a detailed view is show. Again, the data is loaded from the local database. I guess that at this point a GET request for the specific record is requested, either with ETag or If-Modified-Since headers.
3. It happens that the server returns a modified record, thus the local data is modified, so now it's time to update whatever the user is seeing.

**Problem:** If the detailed view is already populated because the local database read was already done when the remote request returns, how can I update the view? I don't think that just replacing current data with the fresher one is acceptable, the user would see a change out of the blue.

Comment: I have found a couple of resources, [here](https://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/) and [here](http://codebrief.com/2013/08/client-sync-for-the-rest-of-us/). What do you think?

Comment: Well, those are more about PATCHing resources than checking if something is obsolete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Satish's answer is absolutely right in terms of what you need your server to do. The gist is that it needs to support ETags and 304 response codes in case the content hasn't changed since the last time you got it from the server. On the client side now, there are essentially three strategies you can follow (each with it's own pros and cons):

1. Only use the cache if the content hasn't changed. That means you will always do a request and will display a progress bar to the user. If the server returns 304, then your content hasn't changed, and the request will be pretty fast (the moment you see that, you display the cached content). If the server actually returns new content, you continue showing the progress bar, and when the content is loaded you display the new content. The good thing about this is that the user will only ever see valid content, therefore avoiding a lot of headaches on your part. The bad thing is that the app does not appear that fast (especially if the content has changed and you are in a very slow connection).
2. Use only the cache for a predefined period and then fallback to first case. There are a couple of cache header to define that period ('max-age' and 'Expires'). Before that period you always use the cache (without doing a request), and after that you do a request and see if the content has changed. The good thing about this method is that for during the period mentioned above, the app is really fast. The bad thing is that there is a possibility that the user is looking at incorrect content.
3. Use both the cache and the network for a predefined period, and then fallback to the first case. You can use the cache headers mentioned earlier in a different way. Instead of only showing the cached content, you can actually display the cached content AND do a request in the background. If that request comes back with a 304, fine, else you will have to update you UI with the new data (expect two responses, one with the cached data and one with the newly retrieved data). The positive with this is that you get both a fast experience and valid data (most of the time). The negative is that you add a lot of complexity to your app (what happens if the user interacts with the stale data, and then a second response comes in etc).

All in all, every strategy is valid depending on the use case. For example, if the user can't interact with the screen that displays the data (like a tv program), the third option is pretty good. If it is crucial that the user sees correct data (a financial app let's say), then the first option is best. If speed is more important than having the latest data (a game or something) then the second option is your best choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. On the third option, which subconsciously was the one I was considering, how would you update the data in a way that it doesn't seem to "suddenly" change? (which is what it would actually do, given that you need to change stale for fresh data).

Comment: This is more of a UI question, but I think what works best for me is displaying your cached data immediately, but while you are doing the request have a spinner showing somewhere on your screen (I believe the actionbar is perfect for this). When the data is loaded again, you need to simply use the new data, do a 'notifyDatatSetChanged' on your adapter, and hide the spinner. That way it's both pretty obvious to the user that the data has changed, but it doesn't break his navigation experience (the listview for example would stay scrolled at the same position if possible).

Answer (score 2):

How efficient the client can do caching is solely dependent on how much support you get from the REST API your client is accessing.

Using ETag is the industry standard to make caching on the client side more efficient and also server to serve the request faster. In short ETag is LIKE an MD5 hash of the content returned. More about ETag here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

If it is a popular API like Google, Facebook etc they inherently support ETags. 
Please look at links below:

ETag usage best explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/etags-reference

- When the client does a GET on the a particular resource, the server when responding back with the content should include an ETag.
- The client should store the ETag for that resource against the data cached.
- Whenever the client is using the cache information, it should verify the cache using the ETag. Can work in multiple ways depending on the service implementation again

  - Make a usual GET on the resource and include the ETag as part of the request. If the content did not change the service will ideally no return any data but will give a specific code like (304 - Not Modified). Client knows that the cache is still valid and continues to use it
  - Make a HEAD call on the resource and the ETag is returned. It is part of the standard HTTP Specification. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html (Refer 9.4). In this case Client will verify the ETag and decide whether or not to make the GET call.

Sample of a resource in the above explaination is like below

```
GET http://serverapi.com/employees/2312312312
```

Comment: Now the thing is, how to support client-side diffs (is there any library for that?) and how to handle the update of the local record taking into account that when the updated data is retrieved, the record is being shown on the screen (although retrieved from the local database). In addition to diff+update the local data, the mobile app should update whatever appears on the screen, and it should do that gracefully.

Comment: You would be better off updating the whole record and not do a diff and update. Its more expensive to query, compare and update only the changes. The update to the data will happen on the background after which on a user event like scroll the updated data can be shown on the screen. There should be other ways to update the app screen on Android but my experience with App Development is limited. I can help you with REST and caching strategy.

Answer (score -1):

The screen update could be handled fairly gracefully by Javascript, rewriting specific elements in the DOM -- optionally applying CSS formatting to call attention to the change in the UI -- if each datum in the UI has a unique ID/container ID or can otherwise be targeted by JS.

A simple/istic way to defeat some caching is to append a query string to the resource you want. For example, a file named testfile.csv can be accessed as easily at testfile.csv?12345 -- and the next time you want to bypass the cache, just update the query string, e.g., testfile.csv?23456. If updating a query string manually is arduous in your context, get a bit more clever at the cost of a modest hit in performance via PHP: call on the resource as testfile.csv to cause the query string to auto-update on every query after the resource is modified; the updated version gets served instead of the cached one.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a hybrid app question nor a website one, thus the javascript and CSS mentions don't make a lot of sense here.

Answer (score -1):

Lately what I've been doing is using GraphQL with Apollo. It handles all this stuff automatically which is plain awesome.